# Windows Service shows as Starting when it's Running

Tags: windows-services, java-service-wrapper

I have created a Windows Service, using Java Wrapper, that basically installs the service and starts it.

I am able to start the service, the application, even run it.  However when I check for Service status in Task Manager or Control Panel-> Administrative Tools-> Services, it shows the service as Stopping or Starting, even though the Service is Running.

What could be the issue here? And is there any resolution for it?

Comment: Have you found the solution in the meantime? I have a similar case. I have a infinite loop running in my Onstart() Method. I think therefore the service also remains in Startting status although it is running.

Answer (score 1):

May be a infinite loop is running in your `Onstart()` Method, Make Sure there isn't a long running loop in `Onstart()`.